# Binary search on vector< struct S> in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stl, binary-search

I would like to use binary search on vector using STL in c++;

```
struct Z{
    int i;
    int j;  
};
struct S{
    Z z;
    int k;
};
vector<S> myvec;
binary_search(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),...);
```

The search condition is  given below .

```
   e.g. binary_search(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),S2);
   and s2.z.i = 1 ; s2.z.j =2; s2.k = 4 ;
```

If i call binary_search with these arguments then it should return true if `there exist any struct S in vector "myvec" such that S.z.i = s2.z.i  and S.z.j = s2.z.j  and S.z.i!=s2.z.i .`
At last how to sort this vector using STL ? It's enough to call `sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end());` .

Comment: Do you have `bool operator < (const S&, const S&)` ?

Comment: I think no , Any way for pair<int,int> is there .

Comment: `binary_search` doesn't know how to compare the `struct Z`'s! As @Jarod42 said, you have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an `operator <`or an comparison function for `struct S`.